# PS Remoting Protocol Version Mismatch

Tags: powershell

I have a disconnected session on Win7 Embedded SP1 32 bit station. I am trying to connect to that session. When I attempt to connect I get an error that suggests PSRemotingProtocolVersion mismatch. I can see my Windows 8.1 station has version 2.3 and the Win7 station has 2.2. How can I correct this issue so I can connect to the disconnected session?

Here is excerpts from my session...

```
PS C:\> Get-PSSession ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org

 Id Name            ComputerName    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  1 Session3        ef-pos-01.fa... Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          None


PS C:\> Get-Pssession ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org | Connect-PSSession
Connect-PSSession : The connect operation failed for session Session3 with the following error message: Connecting to remote server
ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org failed with the following error message : The server that is running Windows PowerShell does not support connect operations on
the protocolversion 2.3  that is negotiated by the client computer. Make sure the client computer is compatible with the build 6.3.9600.16406 and the protocol
version 2.2 of Windows PowerShell. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:46
+ Get-Pssession ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org | Connect-PSSession
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-PSSession], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2141974621,PSSessionConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConnectPSSessionCommand

PS C:\> Enter-PSSession ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org
[ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org]: PS C:\Users\mike.mackenna\Documents> $PSVersiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.17929
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2


[ef-pos-01.faculty.example.org]: PS C:\Users\mike.mackenna\Documents> exit
PS C:\> $PSversionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10105.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   10.0.10105.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem connecting Windows 10 (PS 5) to Server 2012 (PS 3). I could create the session and do whatever, but couldn't reconnect to it, even from the server. Likewise I could create and reconnect on the server (to localhost) but attempting to connect from my computer failed and broke the session.

I resolved this by installing WMF5 on the server to bring it up to PowerShell 5, is now running smoothly.